# Background Check and bankruptcy

Tags: background-check, bankruptcy

Does having declaring bankruptcy 2 years ago affect my background check? I was told I would be hired for a position once my background check cleared.I have not heard back from the potential employer. Is there a way to find out abut the reason why I may not have gotten the job?

Comment: Yes it can.  You would very likely fail a security clearance with US Federal government with a recent bankruptcy on your record.   And I hope that is not your real name.

Comment: If I remembered correctly, you do have a right to see the information they got about you. If I remember right prior to signing the consent form you can ask for a copy of it by checking a field.

Comment: How long has it been?  Have you reached out to HR or the hiring manager yet to check on the status of your application?

Answer (score 3):

Bankruptcy will only be in issue for some background checks. If you were applying for a position where your financial condition was important, then a recent bankruptcy could be a negative factor.

It will also depend on if they asked you to answer questions in advance. Some places ask you to provide a list of everyplace you have worked, and they want a list of all your credit cards, and loans. They may even ask if you have ever declared bankruptcy or defaulted on a loan.

If they did ask you prior to the check, and you didn't tell them about it; then omitting it would be the bigger issue.

They may or may not tell you why you failed. The decision is up to the employer, it isn't up to the person conducting the investigation. They might come back to you to explain any discrepancies found, or they may ask you to explain some confusing information.

If it has been a while you can follow up. Some checks takes only a couple of days, others take months to complete. They should be able to give you a range of times it typically takes.

Comment: Any time security is involved it is a big factor.  The premise is that you can be compromised.

Comment: A list of places you have worked is one thing, but what place would want to know a list of your credit cards? And why should you give that to them?

Comment: Some places like banks, and parts of the federal government need to be able to check on your financial history. Being massively in debt is a sign that you may do something illegal to get out of debt.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, companies will not tell you why you did not pass.

Comment: Many won't even tell you you failed.